# Stripe Mettered Billing what should I use?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm a bit confused by the documentation : `In order for Stripe to compute the number of units consumed during the billing cycle, you must report the customer’s usage by creating usage records`
then : `The usage reporting endpoint is rate-limited, so you might need to exercise caution and avoid making too many separate usage records.`

So what is it saying exactly? after adding some usage for a few customers, my app will stop working? Then what should I use? line items? invoice items?

So far I've created a customer and subscribed him to a plan. How do I increment his usage without limit and risking my app to break for no apparent reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that, if you're in danger of hitting the rate limiting, you should do something to batch up your calls to `https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_items/{SUBSCRIPTION_ITEM_ID}/usage_records`

Instead of POSTing there every time your customer's usage increases, for example, just keep track of it on your side and do one POST daily, at the end of the billing cycle, or at some other interval.

Comment: But even if I limit that call to one per user and per day, I have no way to know how many that would be. if the amout of customers gets really large; what's the limit then?

Comment: If you are limited, you will get a proper HTTP 429 error. This should be dealt with using exponential backoff. In general, if there is something wrong with an endpoint that is not returning 2xx's in response to your requests, it's rarely a good idea to just keep hammering on it indefinitely. Most likely you want some kind of exponential backoff (try again in 2 minutes, then 4, then 8, etc) followed by an alarm or page-out to someone who can inspect things manually (and possibly contact Stripe). API error documentation is here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors

Comment: unpleasant limitation ... So aside from a retry logic, thats the only way to go? I can forget about line items and invoice items to work this out?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to work out, and have adding invoice items might help. Can you explain? You should use the Stripe features that fit your business case (usage or invoice items, depending on how you are billing customers), and then worry about if you have to do something about the rate limit, which is an orthogonal problem entirely.

Comment: the business model would be, an initial payment when subscribing then (service price * nb_used) for different services; I did a plan for a service so far and subscribed a user to it, I added an invoice item just before doing the subscription to make for the initial payment, now I need to set the quantity at the end of the billing date

Comment: Just got a reply from Stripe team, they said exactly the same.For those interested, the limit is around 100 requests per seconds

Comment: I think the thing that has not been answered is how do you actually batch these requests together?

For Metered Billing it states: "It’s best to send usage records in batches to reduce the number of API calls you need to make."

But the endpoint docs only show createUsageRecord not a createUsageRecords which would accept an array of objects...

Any idea on how to do this?