# How to send usages records in batches for Stripe metered billing

Tags: api, request, stripe-payments

I need to make a lot of POST request of usage records for stripes metered billing.

From the comments on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103360/stripe-mettered-billing-what-should-i-use), Stripe has a limit of around 100 requests per seconds. Like someone asked in the comments, the stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered#report-usage) says: It’s best to send usage records in batches to reduce the number of API calls you need to make.

Having that said I can't seem to find any method to send a list of usage records?

Does anyone have any insight about this?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has no way to "batch" a list of usage records so that you can sent multiple records in a single request. The previous post was likely suggesting that you add up the multiple usage records on your end, and then send them to Stripe as a single usage record.